# Howto handle a XML with namespaces?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

If I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope>
<m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
      <m:firmActDescr>ΑΛΛΟ ΛΙΑΝΙΚΟ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΟ ΣΕ ΜΗ ΕΞΕΙΔΙΚΕΥΜΕΝΑ ΚΑΤΑΣΤΗΜΑΤΑ</m:firmActDescr>
      <m:firmActKind>2</m:firmActKind>
      <m:firmActKindDescr>ΔΕΥΤΕΡΕΥΟΥΣΑ</m:firmActKindDescr>
      <m:firmActCode>47191000</m:firmActCode>
   </m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>

   <m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
      <m:firmActDescr>ΛΙΑΝΙΚΟ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΟ ΕΙΔΩΝ ΔΩΡΩΝ ΓΕΝΙΚΑ</m:firmActDescr>
      <m:firmActKind>2</m:firmActKind>
      <m:firmActKindDescr>ΔΕΥΤΕΡΕΥΟΥΣΑ</m:firmActKindDescr>
      <m:firmActCode>47191008</m:firmActCode>
   </m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
</env:Envelope>
```

And I use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h3>Δραστηριότητες</h3>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Δραστηριότητα</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Αριθμός δραστηριότητας</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Περιγραφή δραστηριότητας</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Κωδικός δραστηριότητας</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firmActDescr"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firmActKind"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firmActKindDescr"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firmActCode"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All works fine, but when I have a namespace in the input XML:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://gr/gsis/rgwspublic/RgWsPublic.wsdl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Instead of **no** namespaces:

```
<env:Envelope>
```

The XSLT won't work

My problem is that the XML is received from a 3rd party and I can't control the content. I need to process it as it is. Maybe I can replace the **big env:Envelope** and the small **env:Envelope** within an inside server process, but is there anyway I can make the XSLT work without changing the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match namespaced elements in XSLT you have to declare a namespace prefix in the stylesheet for the same namespace URI, and use that prefix in your XPath expressions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:m="http://gr/gsis/rgwspublic/RgWsPublic.wsdl">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:for-each select="env:Envelope/m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser">
```

(`m:` namespace URI taken from your comment).  Namespace URIs do not have to be real URLs that a browser can fetch, they are simply treated as unique identifiers for the namespace.  Some XML technologies use "URN" identifiers for their namespaces (like `urn:example:namespace`) instead of http URLs.

Comment: the m url is 
<m:rgWsPublicAfmMethodResponse xmlns:m="**http://gr/gsis/rgwspublic/RgWsPublic.wsdl**"> but its strange i cant find that url type of url